# Format notices differently from blockquotes

Tags: feature-request, design

Pretty straight-forward.

An edit notice prepended to a post:

[image: Edit Notice]

A blockquote [in the same thread:](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52971/is-there-any-research-with-respect-to-how-font-weight-affects-readability)

[image: A blockquote now]

To help quickly distinguish between the two better (and make sure people actually see the notice), the notice style should have a different style applied.

Comment: Though the style is different (gray background, no border on the left), the same is true on main SO and I imagine others as well. Never noticed it before but I totally agree with you.